# Allow list reordering when drag from an icon in the list line

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using JQuery UI Sortable to allow reordering elements within a list when dragging element. I would like to improve this processing by allowing reordering only when dragging from an icon present in each element (this icon is a span within the li) not for the whole element.

Is it possible to do this with Sortable?

Thanks very much for your help!
Thierry

Answer (score 2):

Yes, jQuery-UI provides a "handle" option:

> http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-handle
>
> Restricts sort start click to the specified element...
>
> Initialize a sortable with the handle option specified.
>
> ```
> $( ".selector" ).sortable({ handle: 'h2' });
> ```